# Transformation of a Taylor series: "doubling" the derivative order

Tags: analysis, power-series

Suppose a function $f(z)$ has a convergent Taylor expansion:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

Are there general tools to compute $$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{2n} \frac{z^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, f^{(2n)}(0)\frac{z^n}{n!} \text{ ?} $$

I came across this general problem in a more specific context explained in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116296/).

One possible way is to do an integral transform 
$$\dfrac{1}{s} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-z/s} f(z) dz$$
 to remove the factorials, then replace $s \to \sqrt{s}$
 and do the inverse transform. However, this easily leads to very complicated integrals, and does not seem to work for my particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287043/exponential-generating-function-transformation/2794137#2794137) for a solution which is based on an integral formula for the gamma function.